# How to create mock DOM, before simulate method trigger from Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Simulated getData() method click on Test, which results in the following after simulated,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
  68 |     // 
  69 |     getData(){
> 70 |         const elementName = (document.getElementById("sample-element") ;


// Test Case follows.. 
it('Check for getData', () => {
    getData = sinon.spy(wrapper.instance(), 'getData');
    wrapper.update();
    wrapper.find('#getData').simulate('click');
    expect(getData.called).toBe(true);
    getData.restore();  
});

getData(){
    const elementName = (document.getElementById("sample-element");
    fetch(config.getRowDataAPI+elementName)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(allRowData => this.setState({ allRowData },
            () => {
                this.setTable(this.state.allRowData);
            }
        )); 
}
```

Comment: post complete code. Where is value used.

Comment: Updated with complete code.

Comment: Is this code runs ? I see syntax issue on this line - closure missing: const elementName = (document.getElementById("sample-element"));

Comment: This runs, I may missed while typing here...